# TYPE command stops on 0x1A, except when piped to MORE?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io-redirection, control-characters

If I have a binary file with the following contents:

`48 65 6C 6C 6F 1A 48 65 6C 6C 6F`

Then when I run the TYPE command on it, it stops reading at the `1A` character:

```
C:\Temp>type file.bin
Hello
```

However, when I run TYPE again but this time pipe the output to MORE, it produces the following output:

```
C:\Temp>type file.bin|more
Hello→Hello

C:\Temp>
```

Which is more representative of the actual contents of the file than the previous command.

What exactly does piping output to MORE do that makes it print out the entire ASCII representation of the file regardless of the presence of a `1A` character?

Comment: Be aware that `more` modifies Tabulator characters, it changes them to sequences of Space characters; see also its [`/Tn`](http://ss64.com/nt/more.html) option...

Comment: Just a thought - as piped output goes into a file called `something.$$$`. More is getting a block device - a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type` command checks internally where the output will be sent.

If the output stream is the console, the input buffer is checked for the presence of <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> (`0x1A` character) that is handled as EOF.

If the output stream is not the console, then all the characters are handled. This happens not only with pipes, but also redirection.

```
type file.bin | more
type file.bin > con
type file.bin > file.bin.out
```

Both redirected and piped `type` commands will handle all the characters.

This behaviour of `0x1A` character is also present in `copy` command, but in this case it is also [documented](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx).

Comment: I think I can somehow remember that `type` aborted at EOF characters also for files back in MS-DOS days; no clue why they changed it though...

Comment: @aschipfl, It seems it is a [CP/M heritage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040316-00/?p=40233)

Comment: I have a horrible feeling that there is a 32kB limitation on TYPE or MORE, by the way. Or maybe 32,000 lines. Can't remember but watch out.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, `more` is designed for interactive usage. When writing to console it fills a page and waits for a keypress. When its output is redirected it writes 65534 lines and waits for a keypress.

Comment: Files coming from a stream (COM port or console) have no size (unlike block devices like hard drives). So to tell when the file has reached the end Ctrl + Z is added.

Comment: So `copy com1 file` copies a file in text mode - it copies until Ctrl + Z is reached - this is the default for block devices. `copy file file` copies in block mode - the default for block devices. `copy /a file file` copies the file as if it's a text file - it will stop at the first ctrl + Z. It makes no sense to do `copy /b com1 file` as it will not work (compare `copy con file.txt` then enter and Ctrl + Z with copy /b con file.txt` then enter and Ctrl + Z.