# Reading hex value from image in C

Tags: c, hex, readfile

I'm trying to read the hex values from an image file using C. In Linux, this code works fine, but with Windows it reads only the first 334 bytes and I don't understand why.

The code to read the file is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>    
void readHexFile(char* path) {
        FILE *fp;

        if ((fp = fopen (path, "r")) != NULL) {
            struct stat st;
            stat(path, &st);                

            int i;
            int ch;
            for (i = 0; i < st.st_size; i++) {
                ch = fgetc(fp);             
                printf("%x ", ch);
            }

            fclose(fp);
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }
}
```

`st.st_size` comes from `<sys/stat.h>` package and contains the right value (the size, in bytes, of the image file)

This image show what my program outputs, and the actual binary content of the file it is reading:

[image]
As you see after the sequence of `17`, `18`, `19` there is also hex values but my program prints `ffffffff` repeatedly.

Comment: There is noting to be seen. See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. And don't post images of text!

Comment: Yes but the image show right hex values

Comment: *`st.st_size comes from package `* -- what package?

Comment: #include <sys/stat.h>

Comment: `fgets` is probably returning `EOF`. Probably you are not reading the correct length, or you are not using the correct file.

Comment: exact! If I use while... EOF it reads until 0x19 value

Comment: show us more of your code: how do you open the file? It's unclear why you are not looping until something `feof(fp)`

Comment: You should probably also make sure you `fopen()` the file in a binary mode.  That is a significant unix/windows difference.  Its always binary in unix and linux.

Answer (score 5):

You opened the file in a *text* mode, and not as *binary*. Different platforms may behave differently.

In this case, Microsoft Windows decided that this plain text file ends at the first occurrence of `Ctrl+Z` (`0x1A`), and returns `EOF` for all `fgetc` afterwards.

Explicitly state that you want to open the file as binary:

```
fp = fopen ("yourfile", "rb");
```

and the problem goes away.

Comment: Great, but if `0x1A` means `Ctrl+Z`, why are you placing it into parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

I think your loop should look like this:

```
int ch;
while (!feof(fp)) {
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    printf("%x ", ch);
}
```

It's completely unclear to me why you are using `st.st_size` here.

Comment: If I use with while cycle it prints until 0x19 but the file is longer and longer

Comment: Well, your problem was obviously [using text mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41876316/2932052). But what's the reason behind not using `foef`: performance?

Comment: Yes. I used st.st_size to show you wrongs hex. Yes, now I'm already using EOF

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the character `0x1A` (Ctrl+Z) *is* the EOF character for text mode; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708646/type-command-stops-on-0x1a-except-when-piped-to-more).

If you're reading from a binary file like a JPEG, you should do so with first opening the file as binary (`fopen` mode `"rb"`), then `fread` into a pre-allocated buffer, the size of which you would determine with `ftell` with the file pointer at the end of the file:

```
size_t i, len;
char *buffer = NULL;
fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
if(!fp)
   // handle error

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
len = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

buffer = malloc(len + 1);
if(!buffer)
    // handle error

fread(buffer, 1, len, fp);
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    printf("%.2X ", buffer[i]);
}

free(buffer);
buffer = NULL;
```